# How to check if all property values are true?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var myData = {
  "value1": {
      "ext": false
  },
  "value2": {
      "ext": false
  }
};

myData.value1.ext = true;
```

How can I loop through `myData` to see if the `ext` for all the properties in my object are `true`?

Something like this:

```
if (value1.ext === true && value2.ext === true) {
     //do something
}
```

Comment: `if (Object.values(myData).every(v => v.ext)) { /* Yes, they're all true */ } else { /* No, they aren't */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `every()` on `Object.values()`

```js
var myData = {
  "value1": {
      "ext": false
  },
  "value2": {
      "ext": false
  }
};


const res = Object.values(myData).every(x => x.ext);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Perfect this works!~

Comment: @Si8 Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values and check the property.

```js
var object = { value1: { ext: true }, value2: { ext: true } };

console.log(Object.values(object).every(({ ext }) => ext));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every() to check if the values fit the condition:

```js
var myData = {
  "value1": {
      "ext": false
  },
  "value2": {
      "ext": false
  }
};


const areValuesTrue = Object.keys(myData).every(value => myData[value].ext == true)

console.log(areValuesTrue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Object.values and then `map` to get all the value of ext. Then use `includes` to check if any `true` is there

```js
var myData = {
  "value1": {
    "ext": false
  },
  "value2": {
    "ext": false
  }
};
let k = Object.values(myData).map(item => item.ext);
// this will be true if any ext value is true
console.log(k.includes(true))
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to see if they are ALL true.

Comment: @S` do you mean to set the value to true?

Comment: I meant if the `ext` for `value1` and `value2` is `true`